# How to dial a number programmatically in Pocket PC?

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5

I am creating an app using Pocket VB.NET in VS 2008 for the Windows Mobile 6.5. I have a button on the form. When I tap the button, I want the phone to dial a pre-programmed number. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about suing Windows.Mobile.Telephony namespace?

```
public void Talk(string number)
Member of Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony.Phone

Summary:
Places the phone call, using the specified string phone number.

Parameters:
number: The phone number to dial
```

Just add a reference to Windows.Mobile.Telephony in your Smart Device project (targetting at least Windows Mobile 5 SDK (or 6 or higher)):

[image: windows.mobile.telephony]

Comment: This answer works! However there is a strange quirk. If I test this code on my machine using an emulator, it throws an exception, "P/Invoke Failed." However, if I deploy it to my phone and try it, everything is in perfect order. Sometimes Microsoft does strange things!

Comment: Did you test it on a prof. version emulator? The standard emulators do not emulate a phone. There are stdnard or premium variants of windows mobile and only the professionell versions provide the phone stuff.

Comment: I think I did it on a Professional Emulator. I downloaded it from the MSDN website and it said Professional on the link. Like I said, Microsoft does some weird stuff sometimes!